# Rtweet accounts of interest

Tags: r, twitter, data-mining, rtweet

I need to get tweets for a research project using R and specifically the package `rtweet`. I have my premium Twitter API ready and I can get tweets as data frames but what I cannot do is use the accounts of interests functions.

```
    tweets <- search_fullarchive("x", fromDate = 202101010000, toDate = 
202102010000, n = 20, env_name = "env_name", from:y, has:mentions)
```

But I get the following error,

```
Error in search_fullarchive("merkel", fromDate = 202101010000, toDate = 202102010000,  : 
  object 'from' not found
```

Does anyone know a way around this?

Comment: you would need to put the `from:` and `has:` operators inside the query string.

Comment: What should I use to separate different queries, because it did not work with a comma or plus?

Comment: `”merkel from:y has:mentions”` - use a space which is treated as a logical AND

Comment: when I do that it does not come up with any observations I cant seem to understand the problem

Comment: That implies that there are no search results that meet those criteria.

Answer (score -1):

To do query you need environment name:

```
rt <- search_fullarchive("#rstats", n = 300, env_name = "research",
  fromDate = "201401010000", toDate = "201401312359")
```

Comment: I do have my environment name written I just didn't include it for privacy, the code works when I do not include the "from" element to it